# Faster selects when using GUID vs. Select WHERE?

Tags: mysql, database, query-optimization

I have a table with thousands of records. I do a lot of selects like this to find if a person exists.

```
SELECT * from person WHERE personid='U244A902'
```

Because the person ID is not pure numerical, I didn't use it as the primary key and went with auto-increment. But now I'm rethinking my strategy, because I think `SELECTS` are getting slower as the table fills up. I'm thinking the reason behind this slowness is because `personid` is not the primary key.

So my question, if I were to go through the trouble of restructuring the table and use the `personid` as the primary key instead, without an auto-increment, would that significantly speed up the selects? I'm talking about a table that has 200,000 records now and will fill up to about 5 million when done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slowness is due *indirectly* to the fact that the `personid` is not a primary key, in that it isn't indexed because it wasn't defined as a key.  The quickest fix is to simply index it:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `idx_personid` ON `person` (`personid`);
```

However, if it is a unique value, it *should* be the table's primary key. There is no real need for a separate `auto_increment` key.

```
ALTER TABLE person DROP the_auto_increment_column;
ALTER TABLE person ADD PRIMARY KEY personid;
```

Note however, that if you were also using `the_auto_increment_column` as a `FOREIGN KEY` in other tables and dropped it in favor of `personid`, you would need to modify all your other tables to use `personid` instead. The difficulty of doing so may not be completely worth the gain for you.

Comment: @sameold Don't worry too much about the space issue. Hopefully your `personid` column is only as long a `VARCHAR()` as it needs to be. With many millions of rows, storing a short string instead of an int will only really add a few hundreds of megabytes.

Answer (score 1):

You can to create an index to personid.

```
CREATE INDEX id_index ON person(personidid)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE `person ` ADD INDEX `index1` (`personid`);
```

try to index your coloumns on which you are using where clause or selecting the coloumns